# php convert if in function

Tags: php, authentication, user-controls

i have this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])){
    if ($queryusers['user_roll'] != '3'){
        header('location:' . $UrlBase."login");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I would like to turn it into a shorter function, in my project I am going to use this code a lot and I think there is an easier way to call the code, can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Write a `class` file

Comment: @ShreyasAchar Exactly what I want, but how do I convert this code into a class to check if the user is an administrator in just a few words?

Comment: What is the point of having an empty `if` statement? Some code will be here or not?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Try to avoid it using "!" at the beginning but it does not work the same, the code is what I do not understand either. But I'm not going to put code there, so you can remove it.

Comment: In order to help you, we'll need some more code. With just "how to check if the user is an administrator" without code ( have you tried something else? ) we can't be more helpful than that.

Comment: @David - Don't put the '!' at the start of the statement. Put it in the comparison operator if ($queryusers['user_roll'] != '3')

Comment: refactor the typo first.. *role*

Comment: @D.Dimitrov The code works, if in the database I change the 3 for the 1 (that the other users have) it takes me out of the administration panel. What I want is a shorter way to invoke this code.

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['fb_token']) && $queryusers['user_roll'] !== '3'){` is shorter

Comment: I would like to know what the code actually does. From reading the comments I guess that the `($queryusers['user_roll'] === '3')` tests for the administrator role, but what does `(isset($_SESSION['fb_token']))` do? Is that a FaceBook token?

Comment: @FergalAndrews OK this trick works, I update the code then ...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, first I check if the user has already logged in with Facebook, if he has an active token, then I get his Facebook ID, with that ID I check the user's roll in the database.

Comment: I update de code in question!

Comment: @kerbholz -  It may be easier to understand if you could use that syntax but unfortunately that won't work.

Comment: @FergalAndrews You're right, my fault, sorry, need more caffeine. Sorry for interrupting.

Comment: @kerbholz - no apology needed. It was a very reasonable question

Comment: @LawrenceCherone this is de correct... if (isset($_SESSION['fb_token']) && $queryusers['user_roll'] !== '3'){echo "admin";} post de answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code will be self-explanatory:

```
function shortCheck ($qu, $ub) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['fb_token']) && $qu != '3') {
        header('location: ' . $ub."login");
        exit();
    }
}
```

And than you call it like this:

```
if (shortCheck($queryusers['user_roll'], $UrlBase)) {
    echo 'Hello admin!';
} else {
    echo 'Not admin!';
}
```

EDIT:
You're right about naming variables, but this is an example, not production code. For example, I name them in the way that comments are unnecessary, very long and descriptive, so the one who asked question should rename it anyway he/she finds it best.

Maybe I don't understand the question, but summarized, to me it sounds like "I have this checks, I want to reuse it multiple times". This is why functions were invented and somebody suggested creating class for task simple as this one so I wrote this on fly.

Comment: For example, I want to put "if shortCheck is true" hello admin, else "not admin", how can I use your code?

Comment: I know the question asked for a shorter version, and there's not much you can actually do to make it shorter, but using abbreviations like `$qu` and `$ub` isn't the solution, in my opinion. If you come back to this code in a years time, will you still remember what `$qu` and `$ub` stand for? I wouldn't. That would mean extra work to look it up. And abbreviating variable names doesn't make your code any faster. So I think `$qu` should be `$userRole` and `$ub` should be `$urlBase`... (and you forgot to abbreviate that, inside the function)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think the same as you! I hope a better answer.

Comment: I don't think a 'better' answer is possible. You want to check two things, and do two things, that means you need to have some code for that. If Bozidar corrects the bug in the code then that's as good as it gets. Oh, there's another bug: `$qu != '3'` should be `($qu != '3')`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, what I meant was that this code (this answer does not work for me). I'm still waiting for an answer that will help me, why do not you write it?

Comment: I agree with @KIKOSoftware, reducing the variable name down is _definitely not_ the best thing to do. From experience, when younger JustCarty used to do that and I come across it now it infuriates me. That being said, you have provided a very small amount of code that is not very resource intensive and want it 'shortening'; it just seems odd and unnecessary. Also, "user_roll" should be "user_role". A function is a good solution, perhaps, but use descriptive variable names. [Refer](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+you+should+use+descriptive+variable+names)

Comment: I can't write better code because your code is so incomplete. There's nothing to work with.